# How to Pattern Match with Scalaz Tag Generic and use Generic

Tags: generics, tags, pattern-matching, match, scalaz

I would like to be able to do something like the following

```
sealed trait S
trait S1 extends S
trait S2 extends S


case class A[Z <: S](item: URI @@ Z)

class SActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case A[Z](item) =>
       val item2: URI @@ Z = //do some sort of operation
       sender ! A[Z](item2)
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

This is an abstraction from the actual code.  But the issue boils down to, I can't seem to grab Z.  I don't want to know which class it is, I just want to maintain the Tag Z and be able to create another object later using the same Generic class Tag marker.  Can this be done outside of just passing a function that tags as result as Z?

The same problem exists with the following çode, if you're within the case block of the receive method,

```
EitherT((actor ? A(item)).mapTo[A] 
//assume actor responds back with an A and the same Tag
```

A takes a Generic but we don't know which one to assign. I just want to use which ever one it started with (assuming actor holds up to that contract).  The compiler will say that A needs a generic, but it asks for a specific one.  -_-  Thank you, for reading this, and a special thanks to whomever can solve this head-scratcher